# Meaning of 'Händchen lecken' or 'Hand lecken'

Tags: translation

I am reading [Chef Deutsch - Deutsch Chef](https://www.amazon.de/Langenscheidt-Chef-Deutsch-Deutsch-Chef-Klartext-Arbeitsplatz/dp/3468731124), based on the TV series Stromberg.

Excerpts from page 45:

> Chef: Na Frau Burstedt, Sie duften aber mal gut. Noch einiges vor
> heute Abend, was?
>
> Mitarbeiterin: Wieso? Wie soll ich das denn jetzt verstehen?... Stinke
> ich sonst, oder was? Und mein Privatleben geht Sie überhaupt nichts
> an!
>
> ...
>
> Und schon haben Sie den Salat. Ein nett gemeintes Kompliment,
> vorgetäuschtes Interesse am Privatleben, freundschaftlicher
> Umgangston... alles Sachen, nach denen sich jeder männliche
> Mitarbeiter die **stempelkissengeschwärzten Patschehändchen lecken**
> würde.

What exactly is being meant by the bolded section? I know what each of the words means, but what's the essence of the sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard phrase is *sich die Finger nach etwas lecken*, literally "to lick your fingers for something (edible)" and figuratively "to desire something". The idea behind this metaphor is that you would lick your fingers after having eaten tasty food.

The quoted phrase exaggerates this metaphor to achieve a comic effect by having the character lick not only their fingers but their whole hand. In this case, he also has a "soft, fat, limp hand, blackened from the clumsy handling of a rubber stamp pad".